# How to include json file?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I have been trying to connect a json file for a long time but he does not want to see it
please tell me how to do it right

```
   InputStream inputStream = ContentDisplay.class.getResourceAsStream("scr/main/java/resources/embed/embed.json");
   JsonObject embed = (JsonObject) JsonParser.parseReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
   event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(jsonToEmbed(embed)).queue();




java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:168)
at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:76)
at core.task.content.ContentDisplay.onMessageReceived(ContentDisplay.java:48)
at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:361)
at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:88)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:70)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:164)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:127)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:957)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:844)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:822)
at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:996)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

Comment: Try doing just `"/embed/embed.json"` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path contains scr instead of src which I think should be the correct one